# Play sound in the internal speaker, while listening music on a BT A2DP speaker in android

Tags: android

I'd like to play an application sound through internal speaker while device is playing music through an BT external Speaker (A2DP)

I use 2.1 SDK

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try [AudioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setSpeakerphoneOn%28boolean%29) and [AudioManager.setBluetoothScoOn()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setBluetoothScoOn%28boolean%29) to control the audio routing.